# Excel vba unable to get the Vlookup property

Tags: excel, vba

I know there are a lot of these questions on here but I can't see what is going wrong.

I have the following code which checks whether a value is in a column in another workbook.

```
Dim masterWbk As Workbook
Dim oWbk As Workbook
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim Exists As Variant
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim jobnumber As String

    RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn)

    masterWbk.Activate

Set LookupRange = masterWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C100")

    a = 0

    For i = 0 To RowCount - 1

        jobnumber = oWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value

      '  On Error GoTo ExistsError:

        Exists = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobnumber, LookupRange, 1, False)
```

Now the value is definitely in the the lookup range and is formatted the same but the Vlookup just won't work. It works fine as an excel formula.

What have I missed?

Comment: You can use .Find instead of Vlookup

Comment: Where have you set the `masterWbk` and `oWbk`?

Comment: I've set them further up in the code but left them out because it's not that which is causing the issue.

Comment: are you getting an error, or is Exists = false? Is it case sensitive? Are you searching for a numeric value or a string value?

Comment: it's giving me run-time error 1004. It is searching for a string. It is formatted the same in both workbooks so it shouldn't matter

Comment: Disregard the cell "formatting", are your job numbers numeric and would be interpreted by Excel as numeric values, e.g., 1234569? Or are they a mix of alphanumeric characters e.g., "123-dk3A". I think this is a simple case of error happening by trying to look for a string in a range of numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using find it'd look like this-

```
Dim masterWbk As Workbook
Dim oWbk As Workbook
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim Exists As Variant
Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim jobnumber As String

    RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").EntireColumn)

    masterWbk.Activate

Set LookupRange = masterWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C100")

  a = 0

  For i = 0 To RowCount - 1

  jobnumber = oWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Value
  If Trim(jobnumer) <> "" Then
    With lookuprange
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=jobnumber, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Exists = 1
        Else
            Exist = 0
        End If
    End With
  End If
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. I would still be interested in why the vlookup doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the documentation of `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`. In my tests on Excel 2007, if the search string is found, the value of the corresponding cell is returned. If you search for an exact match, you get the dreaded error 1004.

If you want to use Vlookup,

```
...

Dim FoundText as String

...

FoundText=""

On Error Resume Next

FoundText=Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobnumber, LookupRange, 1, False)

On Error Goto 0

Exists= (FoundText <> "")

...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take note of this for future use. So I can only use vlookup for a fuzzy match?

Comment: If you use `Application.Vlookup()` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup()` then in the event of your search value not being found, instead of an error being raised, the return value will be an error, which you can test for using `IsError()`.  Same thing applies to the other WSFunctions: dropping the `WorkSheetFunction` makes everything easier to deal with.

Comment: VLookup should be able to return exact match. The VLOOKUP is working fine in Excel 2010. I am able to return the exact match value from a 1-column lookup array.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for sharing this tip which doesn't seem to be mentioned in the official documentation. **evoandy** you can do an exact match with WorksheetfunctionVlookup but it raises an error if the value is not found

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine in Excel 2010...

I would suggest you're likely getting an error with VLOOKUP because you've dimensioned `jobNumber` as String and despite the worksheet/cell "formatting", the job numbers in your worksheets are likely stored as numeric values.

So, the problem is that "123" <> 123.  Test whether jobNumber is numeric, and then make sure you're passing the right sort of data to the function.

```
If IsNumeric(jobNumber) Then
    Exists = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(jobNumber), lookupRange, 1, False)
Else:
    Exists = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobNumber, lookupRange, 1, False)
End If
```